# Что означают запятые в формуле на языке Паскаль?

Tags: pascal

Что означают эти запятые в формуле написанная на языке Паскаль, так как я учусь на Питоне, поэтому не понимаю что это означает

```
pn:=step(lam/muo,n)/step(2.718,lam/muo)
```

код выглядит так

```
program Model;

uses crt;

var

mx,lam,muo,lp,m,kd,gam,n,kv,i: longint;

ns,s,mui,ksi,k,pn,rr,rn,ir,d,g,l,tot,tob,t,ist,isg,Var1,per,x,y: real;

ch:char;

function step(a,b:real):real;

var x: real;

begin

x:=exp(ln(a)*b);

step:=x;

end;

begin

clrscr;

writeln('Интенсивность потока необработанных документов на входе');

write('системы обработки информации LAM =');

readln(lam);

writeln('Интенсивность обработки документов в каждом канале MUO =');

readln(muo);

writeln('Интенсивность изъятия документов из фонда MUI = ');

readln(mui);

write('Интенсивность обращения каждого внешнего пользователя с запросом LP =');

readln(lp);

write('Число внешних пользователей М =');

readln(m);

writeln('Среднее время задержки внешним пользователем документа при');

write('его получении GAM = ');

readln(gam);

write('06щее количество документов в фонде MX = ');

readln(mx);

write('Площадь фонда, необходимая для хранения одного документа S=');

readln(s);

writeln('Количество сотрудников, необходимое для подготовки и хранения');

write('одного документа NS =');

readln(ns);

writeln('Haжмите любую клавишу...');

repeat until keypressed;

ch:=readkey;

if ch=#0 then ch:=readkey;

clrscr;

writeln('LAM=',lam,'MUO=',muo);

ksi:=lam/muo;

n:=1;

while ksi>=l do

begin

n:=n+1;

ksi:=ksi/n;

end;

writeln('Число каналов обработки информации, необходимое для стационарного');

write('режима работы=');

writeln(n);

readln;

k:=lam/muo;

write('Cpeднee число занятых каналов обработки информации=');

writeln(k:10:4);

readln;

pn:=step(lam/muo,n)/step(2.718,lam/muo);

for kv:=2 to n do pn:=pn/kv;

rr:=1/step(2.718,lam/muo);

for kv:=1 to n do

begin rn:=step(lam/muo,kv)/step(2.718,lam/muo);

for i:=1 to kv do rn:=rn/i;

rr:=rr+rn;

end;

pn:=pn/(rr+pn*ksi/(1-ksi));

ir:=pn*ksi/step(1-ksi,2);

writeln('Cpeднee число необработанных документов, находящихся в');

write('"очереди" на обработку"');

writeln(ir:10:4);

readln;

d:=ir*(-ir+(1+ksi)/(1-Ksi));

write('Дисперсия числа документов в очереди=');

writeln(d:10:4);

readln;

g:=sqrt(d);

write('Среднee квадратическое отклонение числа документов в очереди=');

writeln(g:10:4);

readln;

l:=ir+k;
```

Comment: Приведите [mre]

Comment: я ввел весь код который там был

Comment: А надо ввести [mre]. И отформатировать код

Comment: Странно, разве в питоне аргументы функции не запятыми разделяются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятые разделяют аргументы функции `step`.

Answer (score 3):

```
function step(a,b:real):real;
```

step - функция с двумя аргументами

```
step(2.718, lam/muo)
```

вызов функции с двумя аргументами